# HttpClient DefaultHttpClient() ClientProtocolException is deprecated, how solve it?

Tags: android, httpclient

Below is the problem that I faced:

[image]

I tried `HttpURLConnection`, but openConnection is cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Add more context to your question: include actual code and a description of what you intend to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly know that `HttpClient` is deprecated and you have to use `HttpURLConnection`, It's not totally same as those but as per [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) It should be noted that a `URLConnection` instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation.  You can use [connect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClinetBuilder.create().build() method to replace DefaultHttpClient().

Like:

```
 try{
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mkyong.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
```